# Modify non-static variable from inside static main function

Tags: java, static, scope, non-static

I want to modify a non-static variable from inside my static main function and then return that modified value for use elsewhere. Here is the code:

```
package servletPackage;

public class Blah {

    private int count = 5;
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Blah blah = new Blah();
        blah.count = 10;
    }

    // return Count
    public int getCount()
    {
        return count;
    }

}
```

However, when I access this count from a different file, I get 5 when I want to get 10. Its like count will only stay 10 inside the main, then it changes back to 5. How do I change it so that I can return 10 instead? I tried to get rid of the static in main but then it wouldn't run. Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Edit: here is the javascript code that receives the returned count value of 5 instead of 10

```
function update3() {
      blah.getCount(function(data) {
        dwr.util.setValue("demoReply2", data);
      });
```

Comment: **Object**-oriented programming. Do you have the same object?

Comment: yes. this is all the code. when count is returned, it returns 5 but I want it to return 10 instead.

Comment: You misunderstand me. In the code that gets 5, are you operating over the same **object** as in main? (Don't answer 'yes'.)

Comment: Sorry about that and thanks for the help. The code that gets 5 is from an html file, here is that code: function update3() {
   blah.getCount(function(data) {
     dwr.util.setValue("demoReply2", data);
   });

Comment: Please don't post code in comments since it loses its formatting making it unreadable. Instead, post any new code to the bottom of your original question by [editing your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/24293593/edit).

Comment: Wait, what? That looks like javascript. How does that interact with the java code?

Comment: This is getting more confusing by the minute.

Comment: It is, I'm using dwr-direct web remoting with ajax to access it.

Comment: sigh... your problem is likely just what @SotiriosDelimanolis is getting at. You're likely changing the state of one Blah object, and then checking the state of another.

Comment: The `blah` in your Javascript code refers to a completely different instance than the one in Java.

Comment: Is there a way to check the blah object that I changed the state of?